# what is the base case here in this recursive function?? How its working actually?

Tags: recursion

what is the base case here ?? This is fully functional but how it's working?

```
int isPali(char *s, int l, int r)
{
return ((l == r) || (s[l] == s[r] && isPali(s, l+1, r-1)));
}
int main()
{
char str[100];
scanf("%s", str);

if(isPali(str, 0, strlen(str)-1))
printf("Palindrome\n");
else
printf("Not palindrome\n");
}
```

Comment: Step through it in a debugger to find out.

Comment: ``l == r`` is the base case - but I think that needs to be ``l >= r``: as written, a string of even length will fail because the left and right indexes will pass each other without ever becoming equal.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the only line of the function.  Remember short-circuit logic in evaluating expressions.  The **or** can be changed to

```
if (l == r) 
    return True;
else
    return (s[l] == s[r] && isPali(s, l+1, r-1));
```

Of course, you can now apply the short-circuit to that **else** part:

```
else
    if s[l] == s[r]
        return isPali(s, l+1, r-1);
    else
        return False;
```